# Switch to another angular component on function calling

Tags: angular7, angular7-router

I am trying to call a component from another component on function calls.

In my Project, I have a total of two components.

```
pages/component1/

pages/tables/maintables
```

as mentioned above I have a total of two components defined in Angular 7.

Now in `component1` component, I have a function which is I am calling from another function in the `maintables` component.

below is a code how I am calling a component in function.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/component1');
```

but the above line is not working properly.it is not redirected to the `component1` component.

can anyone help me in this how to call another angular component from a different component?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is both components on the same module or in the different modules...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the problem is resolved now, I import the component in both app.routing.module + another module which is the parent module of my all components.

So it resolves my issues.

Thank you so much to all for your help.